# Make countdown start after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, clock, countdown

I'm creating a kid's game with a timer countdown that starts after the user clicks a button.

The code I'm using initiates the countdown without a problem, but I'd like the countdown to start only after the button is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function(){
(function(){
  var counter = 5;
  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        alert('sorry, out of time');
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, 1000);
})();
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nDYd/8/)

Thank you!
Lauren

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use click event of action link with **id= "startClock"**

```
$("#startClock").click( function(){
   var counter = 5;
   setInterval(function() {
     counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
         span = document.getElementById("count");
         span.innerHTML = counter;
      }
      if (counter === 0) {
         alert('sorry, out of time');
         clearInterval(counter);
       }
     }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a function and add click lister to button to call that function. Do somthing like this.

```js
function startTimer(){
  var counter = 5;
  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        alert('sorry, out of time');
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
function start()
{
    document.getElementById("count").style="color:green;";
    startTimer();
};
```

```css
button
{
font-size:40px;
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
#count
{
   margin-left:20px;
   font-size:30px;
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<span id="count">5</span> seconds
<br>
<button onclick="start()">
START
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `$(selector).on('click',callback);`

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching your function in `onLoad` of the page, instead attach `onClick`

```css
#count
{
font-size:30px;
color:green;
font-weight:bolder;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px blue;
}
#text
{
font-size:30px;
color:blue;
font-weight:bolder;

}
button
{
font-size:25px;
background:black;
color:white;
border-radius:20px;
}
button:hover
{
transition:0.3s linear;
font-size:29px;
background:purple;
color:aliceblue;
border-radius:15px;
}
```

```html
<span id="count">5</span> <span id="text">seconds</span>

<button onclick="start()">Start Clock</button>


<script>
function start(){
  var counter = 5;
  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        alert('sorry, out of time');
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, 1000);
    
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the function get work when you click and in your code you are using `onload` event.

So use click() event of jQuery for your requirement.

```
   $('#startClock').click(function(){
     var counter = 5;
     setInterval(function() {
      counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
   if (counter === 0) {
     alert('sorry, out of time');
     clearInterval(counter);
   }
  }, 1000);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to suggest you to put it in `click` handler of your selector instead of doing that on `window load`:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('#startClock').on('click', doCount);
});

function doCount(){
   var counter = 5;
   setInterval(function() {
      counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
         span = document.getElementById("count");
         span.innerHTML = counter;
      }
      if (counter === 0) {
        alert('sorry, out of time');
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
   }, 1000);
}
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nDYd/12/)

---

Also i need to suggest you that to use `$(function(){});` dom ready function instead of `window.onload = function(){};` just because dom ready does not wait for dom to get fully loaded to execute the script.