# How to make timer begin ONLY when Start Button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

My timer starts when page is opened versus when clicking the Start button.  I have spent hours trying to resolve the problem based on the suggestions I read in this forum:  [Make countdown start after button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670438/make-countdown-start-after-button-is-clicked).  Thank you in advance for your assistance.

My Code:

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }


    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

Comment: um, don't call timer?

Comment: I think using `setInterval` method is better in your case  (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: And after you get it running, click the  start button multiple times and watch the fun and using timeout/intervals for timers is not accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the call to `timer()`:

```
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
//timer();//this causes the timer to start one the page is loaded
```

Also there is a missing brace `}` in your code here:

```
if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    //missing } here
```

See working snippet

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        }
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }


    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
//timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = function(){
    start.disabled = true;
    timer();
};

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    start.disabled = false;
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Implementation using `setInterval` (this way you can avoid the recursive call to `timer()` in your `add` function):

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
        start = document.getElementById('start'),
        stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
        clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
        seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
        t;

    function add() {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
            }
            if (minutes >= 60) {
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
            }


        h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
    }
    function timer() {
        t = setInterval(add, 1000);
    }
    //timer();


    /* Start button */
    start.onclick = function(){
        start.disabled = true;
        timer();
    };

    /* Stop button */
    stop.onclick = function() {
        clearInterval(t)
        start.disabled = false;
    }

    /* Clear button */
    clear.onclick = function() {
        h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
        seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
    }
```

```html
    <h1></h1>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: using `setinterval` would be better than `setTimeout` in this case

Comment: Click the start button multiple times

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher added an implementation using `setInterval`

Comment: @epascarello I've fixed that

Comment: THANK YOU!!   It worked perfectly.  In the past, I have resolved many coding issues simply by reading the posts in this forum....this was the first time I requested help.  Your response is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please direct me how to do so.  I've been searching for an "accepted" type click, but can't locate one.  Again, this is the first time I requested help from this forum.

Comment: @CarolDevlin look at the left hand side of the top of the answer, there should a check mark beside it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Remove `timer()` underneath `function timer() {`. If that doesn't help, try removing `timer()` in `add()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You call `timer()` in your code, before the start button is pressed.

```
timer();
```

Remove that line from your code and test it; the timer shouldn't begin on page load once you do that.